# Will path-range-index added to parent element also results for child element?

Tags: xml, marklogic

Consider that following is a part of `XML` data:

```
<Author>
   <Level1>Justice</OrganizationLevel1>
   <Level2>National Justice</OrganizationLevel2>
   <URL>http://www.usdoj.gov</URL>
</Author>
<Editor>
   <Level1>Association</OrganizationLevel1>
   <Level2>Films for Sciences</OrganizationLevel2>
   <URL>http://www.films.com</URL>
</Editor>
```

If a `path-range-index` is added to `Editor` (parent) element in ML6 will its child-element also reflect this `path-range-index`.

Can anyone explain this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; a path range index only indexes the node(s) identified by the specified xpath. If you need range indexes on the child-elements, then you'll need to specify path range indexes for each of them individually.